# Can my starter cause slow or no cranking

Tags: battery, starter, crv, no-crank-no-start

I have a 2008 Honda CRV recently the car has refused to start I called AAA and they came with a battery pack to jump the car but when I turn the key it barely turns over and does not start the lights on the dashboard them a little bit. I have drain the battery on this vehicle before and the behavior seems very similar to what happens when I completely drain the battery AAA man thought it was the starter but it did actually turn over once or twice just very slowly I’m wondering if perhaps both my battery and his battery pack or bad or if it is indeed the starter in the past when I’ve had a start to go bad usually makes a clicking noise or doesn’t turn over at all just wondering if there’s anything else I can do before I get the car towed.

Update I took the battery and got it tested it was indeed bad but even after I got a new battery and swapped out the car won’t start now it just makes a high-pitched wearing noise when I try to turn it over no clicks no turnover does this mean that the starter is bad for sure

Comment: What is the voltage at the battery? If below 12vdc at rest, it's probably the battery. If the battery is good, then take the starter off and get it tested.

Comment: I had the battery tested out on O-Zone and they said that the battery was bad so I replaced it but it turns out that not only was the battery bad but the starter is now not working

Comment: Sounds more like a poor earth connection to me- the starter is not the only electrical system that is struggling to work. To verify this, turn the key to position 2, don't try to start the engine, turn on every electrical thing you can find- lights, wipers, fan blower. If they work well, suspect the startermotor, if they do not, suspect the wiring from battery to car body/battery terminal connectors

Comment: Ended up being the battery first, then the AAA guy fried the starter solenoid by try to crank it 20 times in a row with low voltage , had to replace the starter